# Visual list of all installed fonts with respective pangram phrase?

Tags: php, linux, fonts

I am tired of searching erratically the perfect font by scrolling endlessly with Gimp all fonts so I thought: "Why not build a visual list of pangrams for each font".

[image: font list with pangram]

I tried therefore building a php script which looked for .ttf and otf files in .fonts/ folder and which printed the css @font-face, however the result sucked because each font has its own quirks even under only firefox.

```
<?php
$path = "/home/cinthya/.fonts/";

//get all text files with a .txt extension.
$texts = glob($path . "*.ttf");
$i = 0;

//print each file name
foreach($texts as $text)
{
    echo "  @font-face {
    font-family: ".substr($text,22, (strlen($text)-26)).";<br>
    src: local('".substr($text,22, (strlen($text))-26)."'),  local('".substr($text,22, (strlen($text))-26)."'), url('".substr($text,22, (strlen($text)))."');<br>
    font-weight:normal;<br>
}<br>";
    echo "#div".$i." p {
    font-family: '".substr($text,22, (strlen($text)-26))."', Fallback, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
  }<br>";
  $i++;
}

$texts = glob($path . "*.otf");
$j = 0;
foreach($texts as $text)
{
  echo "<div id=\"div".$j."\"><p>Zwölf Boxkämpfer jagen Eva quer über den großen Sylter Deich</p></div>\n";
  $j++;
}
```

Isn't there some stupid program which prints a nice vertical list of fonts examples by just only specifying a pangram and the folder containing the fonts?
Or some way to do it?

I know I should not ask for software suggestion but this is a necessity for which any quick and dirty solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

"Open the Fonts dialog (Windows->Dockable Dialogs->Fonts)

Right click any font in the list

Choose 'Render Font Map'

In the dialog that appears, leaving the 'Filter (regexp)' blank will list all your installed Fonts."

Source: http://gimpforums.com/thread-font-examples
This forum thread clearly lists the steps for rendering a sample of each font in your GIMP library. I hope that this helps someone who stumbles on this question like I did!

Comment: interesting solution, however I have close to 1000 font files and after 10 minutes of crunching it tries to render a giant image of 1.6GB which of course crashes. This solution might be viable for some 100 of fonts not more.

Comment: Thank god this runs in a different thread. I started doing this without having saved my work, but I was able to save while it was running.